# automate OWASP penetration test in python using python-owasp-zap-v2.4 package

Tags: python, owasp, zap

I need to automate OWASP penetration test in python script using python-owasp-zap-v2.4 package.
so I need to run this command

```
scanid = zap.spider.scan(target, apikey=apikey)
```

any idea which apikey ,and how to get it ?

Answer (score 0):

The ZAP API key is generated by random when you first start ZAP. This is fine for manual testing but not so good for automated testing.
However you can specify the API key when you start ZAP using the commandline option:

```
-config api.key=change-me-9203935709
```

For more details see https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQapikey